# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' 4

Tags: python, list, return-value, reverse

```
from collections import deque
def muladd(f1,f2_inv):
    global ans 
    for j in f1:
        ans = f1[j]*f2_inv[j]

f1 = [2,3,7,5,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
f2 = [0,0,0,0,8,7,6,5,9,0,0,0,0]

conv = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
f2_inv = f2.reverse()

for i in conv:
    conv[i]= muladd(f1,f2_inv)
    print conv[i]
    f1.rotate(1)
​
```

I am not able to run the code.

When I run this code I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you post the whole traceback?

Comment: Shouldn't the loop be `for i in range(len(conv)):`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    conv[i]= muladd(f1,f2_inv)
  File "main.py", line 7, in muladd
    ans = f1[j]*f2_inv[j]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I think list object has no attribute `rotate`

Comment: how do I do the circular rotation of the elements in the list ?

Comment: What is f2_inv = f2.reverse() supposed to do? It assigns None to f2_inv---- It should reverse the elements in the list

Comment: And please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially #1

Answer (score 2):

`reverse()`, like many methods that operate on lists, does not return anything, but modifies the list in-place. So `f2` is None. You should use the standalone `reversed()` function.

```
f2_inv = list(reversed(f1))
```

or slicing:

```
f2_inv = f1[::-1]
```

(Note, there are other issues with this code, such as the fact that `i` is always 0 in your loop because you iterate over a list of only 0s.)

Comment: it causes `TypeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: basically all I want to do is to perform convolution of two functions . here I have taken two lists which contain numbers and try to perform its convolution using sliding tape method .. how can I improve ?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop

```
for i in conv:
  conv[i]= muladd(f1,f2_inv)
  print conv[i]
  f1.rotate(1)
```

`i` will be an object (it loops over all the objects of `conv`, so `i` is an object instead of an index number). This way you cannot use `conv[i]`. To be able to use `i` as an index, use:

```
for i in range(len(conv)):
  conv[i]= muladd(f1,f2_inv)
  print conv[i]
  f1.rotate(1)
```

(this is not the cause of your error, but will cause problems if yours is fixed, as `conv[i]` would always be `conv[0]`, because `i` is `0` instead of the current index number)